# Select Record Conditional Random #MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, one for still images and one with this property, both are linked so that a property can have no pictures. Would you like to "select" where I can select all properties and just a random picture of this property. How to do this?

Exemplifying best, I pick a random image from the image table for each record in the table that has motionless pictures. Want to select this randomly. What I could do was to select all images for each record of the bank property. I just want each record imovel a respective random image.

The sql is below:

```
select distinct 

    imovel.nome as 'NOME',
    imovel.valor as 'VALOR',
    imovel.quarto as 'QUARTO',
    imovel.suite as 'SUITE',

    cidade.nome as 'CIDADE',
    bairro.nome as 'BAIRRO',
    (select distinct nome from tabimagem img where img.cdimovel = imagem.cdimovel order by rand() limit 1) as 'IMAGEM'

from tabimovel imovel

    inner join tabcidade cidade on imovel.cdcidade = cidade.codigo
    inner join tabbairro bairro on imovel.cdBairro = bairro.codigo                    
    inner join tabimagem imagem on imagem.cdImovel = imovel.codigo

order by rand()
```

Comment: So, is this SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Im sorry but it is very difficult to understand your question.  I assume english is not your first language, maybe there is someone who can help you translate it better?

Comment: sorry, I'm Indian  #TranslateGoogle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL server add `TOP 1` after `SELECT`, and order as `ORDER BY NEWID()`.

In MySQL, order should be `ORDER BY RAND()`, followed by `LIMIT 1`.

That should work.